# UITableviewCell returning as nil inside block

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My implementation of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    BSProductCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:BSProductCellIdentifier];

    cell.productImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder"];

[[BSImageLoader sharedInstance] getImageWithURL:self.dataSourceArray[indexPath.row] withCompletionBlock:^(UIImage *image, BOOL fromCache, NSString *error){
    BSProductCell *tableCell = (BSProductCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableCell.productImageView setImage:image];
    NSLog(@"%@", tableCell);
}];
    return cell;

}
```

The `getImageWithURL:withCompletionBlock:` either downloads the image from the specified URL if it cannot find it within the local cache or just returns it from the cache. At first, when the view loads and the cells get populated all the things go as expected: the images are being downloaded and then placed within the cells. The problem is when I start scrolling the tableview, the NSLog shows `(null)`. I just cannot figure out why the `tableCell` object is null.

**PS:** I wrote my example after following an almost identical [example from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html).
Also I checked and neither `self.tableView` nor `indexPath` are not nil inside the block.

Answer (score 0):

The block is asynchronous, you should create your cell outside the block and only set the image inside :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    BSProductCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:BSProductCellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell = [[BSProductCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:BSProductCellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.productImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder"];

    [[BSImageLoader sharedInstance] getImageWithURL:self.dataSourceArray[indexPath.row] withCompletionBlock:^(UIImage *image, BOOL fromCache, NSString *error){

        //Here you check that the cell is still displayed
        if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]){
            [cell.productImageView setImage:image];
            NSLog(@"%@", cell);
        }
    }];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: For what you call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` from the same method ?

Comment: Why is the block asynchronous? In the case when the image is fetched from the cache the block is executed immediately, and that's when the issues arise

Comment: And another issue regarding your solution: if the block is executed after the cell has been reused, a wrong image will be displayed.

Comment: A block is always asynchronous, i don't believe the issue is about cache. A block also keeps an instance of the current cell, you don't have to worry about wrong cell.

Comment: Not a wrong cell.. rather a wrong image. Say initially the cell has to display image A which is large and it's download takes a while. If you scroll the table view, and the cell gets reused, another image will be displayed, for the specific row. Now, if the result of the request for image A arrives, the image will be changed, and therefore a wrong image will be displayed(image A instead of whatever was displayed)

Comment: That's a really good point, i've updated my answer accordingly. However this is a simple a quick fix but that could be improved. A better way to do that would be to cancel the request you're sending and not just ignore the result. Here is a good link about it : http://stavash.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/advanced-issues-asynchronous-uitableviewcell-content-loading-done-right/